# How we call the string holder?

Tags: objective-c, string

I don't know how to say, here is the example:

Objective C Code:

```
NSLog(@"This is a test ok, %@?", yourName);
```

What is the `%@` called? a String place holder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%@` is a so-called *format specifier*, like `%d` to print decimal numbers or `%f` to print floats. The `%@` is specific to Objective-C and calls `description` on the passed object. This  method in turn returns a string that then gets printed. So this is roughly equivalent to:

```
@"This is test ok, " + [yourname description] + @"?"
```

In the case of `NSString`, the description merely returns itself. However, you can override `description` for your own objects to provide a useful descriptive string.

Answer (score 3):

`%@` is a [Format Specifier.](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog) This particular one expects a any Objective-C object, not only an `NSString`.